# Group subarrays when one value is the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to group together the data in an array of arrays when the value at array[i][0] is common.

Can I use `Array.map()` to do this?

I've been toying with another solution, which is to create a new array with just the unique values and compare it back to the original array, but I can't figure out the logic to craft the result into what HighCharts wants.

I'm pretty confident that if I can figure out how to do this array manipulation, I can also figure out the logic to automate HighCharts, which would make my Saturday :)

I have:

```
var array = [
    ["name1","date1"],
    ["name1","date2"],
    ["name2","date1"],
    ["name2","date1"]
];
```

And want to turn it into:

```
var array = [
    [
        ["name1","date1"],
        ["name1","date2"]
    ],
        ["name2","date1"],
        ["name2","date2"]
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be possible to do this in a single loop. I would be inclined to create an object in a first pass, and then build the data structure in a second. Something like:

```
var obj = oldArray.reduce(function(memo, item) {
  // Get the unique value you're interested in, e.g. "name1"
  var key = item[0];
  // If you've already got it, push this value on the end
  if (memo[key]) {
    memo[key].push(item);
  } else {
    // otherwise, create a new array with this single value
    memo[key] = [ item ];
  }
  // Don't forget to return memo, or you'll have one of those
  // "bang your head against the wall" moments
  return memo;
}, {});

// create a new array and push all the values on
var newArray = [];
for (var k in obj) {
  newArray.push(obj[k]);
}

// or an alternative way to do the same thing
var newArray = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, k) {
  memo.push(obj[k]);
  return memo;
}, []);
```

Comment: It CAN be done in one loop, but I think it would be less efficient than what you have here (because building up the array as you go would require repeated searches into the output array, less efficient than addressing object properties)

Comment: This worked for me - thanks! :)  I also have another highcharts related question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29906901/convert-json-data-into-format-in-highcharts-basic-line-chart

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in a couple of loops by removing items into named properties.

```
function returnOrderBy0Position(start)
{
    start.tmp={};
    while (start.length>0)
    {
        var o = start.shift();
        start.tmp[o[0]] = start.tmp[o[0]] ? start.tmp[o[0]] : [];
        start.tmp[o[0]].push(o);
    }

    for (var p in start.tmp)
        start.push(start.tmp[p])

    start.tmp=null;
}

returnOrderBy0Position(array); // call this on your array
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't really use map.  You would have to aggregate (reduce) the results.

```
function regroup(arr) {
    var groups = {};
    return arr.reduce(function (result, item) {
        var key = item[0];
        var group = groups[key];
        if (!group)
            result.push(group = groups[key] = []);
        group.push(item);
        return result;
    }, []);
}
```