# Convert JSON data into format in Highcharts' basic line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

Using Javascript, I am trying to convert some JSON data into the format used in Highcharts' basic line chart.

**What I have to start with:**

```
originalArray = [
    ['valueA', 1],
    ['valueA', 0],
    ['valueB', 9],
    ['valueB', 9],
    ['valueB', 3],
    ['valueC', 11]
]
```

**And what I'm trying to create using the above:**

```
desiredArray = [{
      name: 'valueA',
      data: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'valueB',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'valueC',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
  }]
```

For some additional context, the 0-11 in `originalArray[i][1]` references a month (0 = January), and the `desiredArray` is a list of unique names and a count of their occurrences by month.

**So far, I can:**

- Convert the data into a new array of objects
- For each unique name in `originalArray`

  - Create a new object in the `desiredArray`, and set the `name` attribute
  - Add a `data` attribute that contains an empty array

**But then I run into trouble, and can't figure out how to:**

- Loop through the `originalArray`

  - If the name in the `originalArray` matches the name in the `desiredArray`

    - Increment a counter in the matching `seriesArray[i].data` array, using the value of `originalArray[i][1]` as the index (it always be 0-11).

**So I'm asking:**

1. What's a good way to iterate across my `originalArray`, match up unique values, and **then act only on those matches** to push to the `desiredArray`.
2. What's the best way to increment the counters in `desiredArray[i].data`

I'm open to using libraries, such as underscore.js. Have been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now, so pretty much anything goes within the bounds of Javascript.

Comment: Incidentally, the counts in your valueB entry in desiredArray are wrong, I think...there should be a 1 in data[3]?

Comment: @SMcCrohan good catch, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with proper array initialization, now.

```
var max = originalArray.reduce(function(p,c){return Math.max(p,c[1]);},0);

var initSums = function(size) {
    var arr = new Array(size);
    for (var i=0;i<size;i++)
        arr[i]=0;
    return arr;
}

var map = originalArray.reduce(function(sums,val){
    if (!sums.hasOwnProperty(val[0])) {
        sums[val[0]] = initSums(max+1);   
    }
    sums[val[0]][val[1]]++;
    return sums;
},{});

var desiredArray = Object.keys(map).map(function(key) {
    return {name: key, data: map[key]}; 
});
```

What we're doing here is a multi-step process:

1. Decide how big our arrays are going to need to be, by first scanning for the largest value in the original array.
2. Use an object to aggregate the counts (using `Array.reduce()`).
3. Transform the object and its properties into an array of name/data pair objects (using `Array.map`).

Comment: Just a note -- as I understand the question, not only is the search for `max` unnecessary, but it's actually harmful. The array should always be of length 12, one for each month. If `valueC` was removed from `originalArray`, the result wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Hmm, agreed. Not sure if that was added to the question later or if I read past it, but if the arrays are reliably always the same size then yes, that check is extraneous.

Comment: Nah, it was there from the start. I should have commented, perhaps, instead of just providing my solution. @SeanConnelly might come back if he finds it doesn't work out. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: An improvement on S McCochran's solution, skipping the extraneous search for the maximum value in `originalArray`, since there should always be 12 elements of each data array, one per month.

```
function formatForHighcharts(array) {

  // Create a map from value name to array of month counts
  var map = originalArray.reduce(function(sums, pair) {
    var key = pair[0], val = pair[1];

    if(!(key in sums))
      sums[key] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

    // val is the month index, which corresponds directly to array index, so increase that
    sums[key][val]++;

    return sums;
  }, {});

  // Map the object to an array of { name: ..., data: ... } pairs
  var formatted = Object.keys(map).map(function (key) {
    return { name: key, data: map[key] };
  });

  return formatted;
}
```

Usage:

```
var desiredArray = formatForHighcharts(originalArray);
```